# Changing filename in BlobBuilder to be passed as FormData on XHR

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, mime-types, multipartform-data

I'm currently trying to upload an ArrayBuffer to a server (which i can't change) that expects the file i'm uploading on a multipart/form-data format. The server extracts from the `Content-Disposition` part the `filename` that will be saved and under `Content-type` the MIME type which will be used when serving the file. Currently, i'm succesful on uploading the file with:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var fdata = new FormData();
var bb;

if (WebKitBlobBuilder) {
    bb = new WebKitBlobBuilder();
} else if (MozBlobBuilder) {
    bb = new MozBlobBuilder();
} else if (BlobBuilder) {
    bb = new BlobBuilder();
}

bb.append(obj.array);

fdata.append('file', bb.getBlob("application/octet-stream"));

xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.send(fdata);
```

But the headers are sent as the browser likes, on Chrome for example:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
```

I've contemplated saving it to a temporary file with FileWriter API and then upload it, but that just isn't right.

**When answering, take into account**:

- The server can't be modified, nor i'm willing to select another server provider.
- It must work at least on Firefox and Chrome (my app is alredy limited to those two browsers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just solved it myself, thanks to a Chromium issue pointing me to the answer on w3c standard draft [XMLHttpRequest](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#the-append-method). Basically i should change:

```
fdata.append('file', bb.getBlob("application/octet-stream"));
```

to:

```
fdata.append('file', bb.getBlob("application/octet-stream"), obj.filename);
```

And it gives the desired result.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work in Firefox, filed a bug: [link[(https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=736324)

Comment: I'm working on it already: Bug 690659 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=690659 (The patch already works but there are some problems with how i handle certain things). Please, don't duplicate bugs.