# Ajax upload -- how to get the FormData filename vs the raw file filename

Tags: javascript, upload

Doing the standard file upload technique of creating a `FormData` and using `append` to put the rawFile from the input in the FormData.

The issue is when I look at `file.name`, I see one thing (the same thing I see in the file explorer), and when I look at what is sent on the request in the form, the file name has a `.zip` appended on the end of it.  That is not unexpected, because the file being uploaded is really a zip, even though the extension is not zip...

Is there any way to see the filename in the FormData object?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest/FormData):

> If you specify a Blob as the data to append to the FormData object, the filename that will be reported to the server in the "Content-Disposition" header will vary from browser to browser

Your best best is to specify the filename manually, by providing a third argument to `.append()`, though it's not clear if every browser supports this yet. See the [FormData spec](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#the-append()-method). You can get the filename from `name` property of the `File` object that you're about to upload.

See also: [Changing filename in BlobBuilder to be passed as FormData on XHR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495301/changing-filename-in-blobbuilder-to-be-passed-as-formdata-on-xhr)