# Mime Type vs Extension Check, which method is better to check file type?

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm creating a script to upload image file. There are two ways to verify if the file is an image.

First one is by checking the extension:

```
$extension = strtolower(substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1, strlen($filename) - strrpos($filename, '.')));
if ($extension == "jpg") // UPLOAD
```

Another one is by checking the mime type:

```
$imageinfo = getimagesize($filename);
if ($imageinfo['mime'] == "image/jpeg") // UPLOAD
```

Which one is the better method to verify if the file is an image?

Comment: Fair enough. But I want to know which one of these methods is better?

Comment: Both are not that reliable. You might want to look at the PHP Fileinfo module. Though stil not 100% reliable.

Comment: If you want to make sure the file is an image using a library like Imagick is more reliable I think

Comment: Both can easily be forged, so neither is really better or worse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first one, because not every MIME type has a fixed file extension. Also, MIME types like ***`application/octet-stream`*** can refer to multiple file extensions. and also you can use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) for getting file extension.

check below links

[How to extract a file extension in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/173876/7244426)

[Not every MIME type has a fixed file extension...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16511092/7244426)