# Force the download of a file read by Flysystem from AWS S3

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3, flysystem

Good morning, everyone,

My question is simple, I use Flysystem (on Symfony) to recover a resource from S3 (through DigitalOcean). I would like to be able to return it for download to the user. Here is my code:

```
    $client = new S3Client([
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => '',
            'secret' => '',
        ],
        'region' => '',
        'version' => 'latest',
        'endpoint' => 'https://ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com',
    ]);

    $adapter = new AwsS3Adapter($client, '');

    $filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);
    $filename = 'file.png';
    $stream = $filesystem->readStream('file.png');
    $contents = stream_get_contents($stream);
    fclose($stream);

    $response = new Response($stream);
    $disposition = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $filename
    );
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $disposition);

    return $response;
```

=> The file is corrumpted...

Any ideas?
Thank you very much for your helping.
Guillaume

UPDATE
When I check with text file, I receive contents of my file but with header :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 27 Sep 2018 06:59:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Authorization,Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=toto.png
Link: <http://localhost/api/public/api/docs.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation"
Content-Length: 517
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Any ideas to download only file content, and for all file type? Thank you very much for all, Guillaume

Comment: does file finish downloading? Might have to add some blocking process to make sure file is downloaded before continuing.

Comment: Just like that?
        `$stream = $filesystem->readStream('sounds/toto.png');`
        `while (!feof($stream)) {`
            `echo fread($stream, 1024);`
        `}`
        `$contents = stream_get_contents($stream);`
        `fclose($stream);`
It doesn't work any better :(

Comment: hmm maybe its a permissions thing? Try on an public bucket to see if you can get the file, if that works then may have to configure the s3 bucket to get a presigned url.

Comment: This is strange, because I get the right file headers (mp3, png, etc.) and almost the right file sizes. I really feel like he's getting the files back, but they're corrupted.

Comment: I just asked and looked at their documentation, if there was a problem accessing the files, I should get an error. There I have no mistakes, I do have data, but corrupted. I keep looking for....

Comment: What do you mean by "corrupted"?

Comment: @mblaettermann I can't open downloader files. I've check with text file, it's working but header is also downloaded..

Comment: Good morning, everyone,
I updated my question above, I still can't download my resources correctly from S3. Maybe someone has some suggestions for solutions?
Have a good day, everyone,
Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a few years old but hopefully this helps someone. I am able to force the download but do note I use Flysystem to access a file from AWS S3 directly.

```
$client = new S3Client([
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => '',
        'secret' => '',
    ],
    'region' => '',
    'version' => 'latest'
]);
$adapter = new League\Flysystem\AwsS3V3\AwsS3V3Adapter($client, 'bucket-name');
$filesystem = new League\Flysystem\Filesystem($adapter);
try {
    $listing = $filesystem->listContents('name-of-folder-in-bucket/', false);

    foreach ($listing as $item) {
        $path = $item->path();

        if ($item instanceof FileAttributes) {
            // handle the file
            try {
                $response = $filesystem->readStream($path);
                $fileName = explode("/", $path);
                $fileSize = $filesystem->fileSize($path);
                $mimeType = $filesystem->mimeType($path);
                $fileExtension = mimeToExtension($mimeType);

                header("Pragma: public");
                header("Expires: -1");
                header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
                header("Content-Type:application/" . $fileExtension);
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName[1] . '"');
                header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

                header('Content-Length: ' . $fileSize);
                header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
                fpassthru($response);
            } catch (FilesystemException | UnableToRetrieveMetadata $exception) {
                echo "couldnt retrieve file metadata";
            }
        } elseif ($item instanceof DirectoryAttributes) {
            // handle the directory
        }
    }
} catch (FilesystemException $exception) {
    // handle the error
    echo "folder does not exist";
}
```

And here is the code for the function mimeToExtension, taken from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53662733/13922606):

```
function mimeToExtension($mimeType)
{
    $mimeMap = [
        'video/3gpp2'                                                               => '3g2',
        'video/3gp'                                                                 => '3gp',
        'video/3gpp'                                                                => '3gp',
        'application/x-compressed'                                                  => '7zip',
        'audio/x-acc'                                                               => 'aac',
        'audio/ac3'                                                                 => 'ac3',
        'application/postscript'                                                    => 'ai',
        'audio/x-aiff'                                                              => 'aif',
        'audio/aiff'                                                                => 'aif',
        'audio/x-au'                                                                => 'au',
        'video/x-msvideo'                                                           => 'avi',
        'video/msvideo'                                                             => 'avi',
        'video/avi'                                                                 => 'avi',
        'application/x-troff-msvideo'                                               => 'avi',
        'application/macbinary'                                                     => 'bin',
        'application/mac-binary'                                                    => 'bin',
        'application/x-binary'                                                      => 'bin',
        'application/x-macbinary'                                                   => 'bin',
        'image/bmp'                                                                 => 'bmp',
        'image/x-bmp'                                                               => 'bmp',
        'image/x-bitmap'                                                            => 'bmp',
        'image/x-xbitmap'                                                           => 'bmp',
        'image/x-win-bitmap'                                                        => 'bmp',
        'image/x-windows-bmp'                                                       => 'bmp',
        'image/ms-bmp'                                                              => 'bmp',
        'image/x-ms-bmp'                                                            => 'bmp',
        'application/bmp'                                                           => 'bmp',
        'application/x-bmp'                                                         => 'bmp',
        'application/x-win-bitmap'                                                  => 'bmp',
        'application/cdr'                                                           => 'cdr',
        'application/coreldraw'                                                     => 'cdr',
        'application/x-cdr'                                                         => 'cdr',
        'application/x-coreldraw'                                                   => 'cdr',
        'image/cdr'                                                                 => 'cdr',
        'image/x-cdr'                                                               => 'cdr',
        'zz-application/zz-winassoc-cdr'                                            => 'cdr',
        'application/mac-compactpro'                                                => 'cpt',
        'application/pkix-crl'                                                      => 'crl',
        'application/pkcs-crl'                                                      => 'crl',
        'application/x-x509-ca-cert'                                                => 'crt',
        'application/pkix-cert'                                                     => 'crt',
        'text/css'                                                                  => 'css',
        'text/x-comma-separated-values'                                             => 'csv',
        'text/comma-separated-values'                                               => 'csv',
        'application/vnd.msexcel'                                                   => 'csv',
        'application/x-director'                                                    => 'dcr',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'   => 'docx',
        'application/x-dvi'                                                         => 'dvi',
        'message/rfc822'                                                            => 'eml',
        'application/x-msdownload'                                                  => 'exe',
        'video/x-f4v'                                                               => 'f4v',
        'audio/x-flac'                                                              => 'flac',
        'video/x-flv'                                                               => 'flv',
        'image/gif'                                                                 => 'gif',
        'application/gpg-keys'                                                      => 'gpg',
        'application/x-gtar'                                                        => 'gtar',
        'application/x-gzip'                                                        => 'gzip',
        'application/mac-binhex40'                                                  => 'hqx',
        'application/mac-binhex'                                                    => 'hqx',
        'application/x-binhex40'                                                    => 'hqx',
        'application/x-mac-binhex40'                                                => 'hqx',
        'text/html'                                                                 => 'html',
        'image/x-icon'                                                              => 'ico',
        'image/x-ico'                                                               => 'ico',
        'image/vnd.microsoft.icon'                                                  => 'ico',
        'text/calendar'                                                             => 'ics',
        'application/java-archive'                                                  => 'jar',
        'application/x-java-application'                                            => 'jar',
        'application/x-jar'                                                         => 'jar',
        'image/jp2'                                                                 => 'jp2',
        'video/mj2'                                                                 => 'jp2',
        'image/jpx'                                                                 => 'jp2',
        'image/jpm'                                                                 => 'jp2',
        'image/jpeg'                                                                => 'jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg'                                                               => 'jpeg',
        'application/x-javascript'                                                  => 'js',
        'application/json'                                                          => 'json',
        'text/json'                                                                 => 'json',
        'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml'                                      => 'kml',
        'application/vnd.google-earth.kmz'                                          => 'kmz',
        'text/x-log'                                                                => 'log',
        'audio/x-m4a'                                                               => 'm4a',
        'audio/mp4'                                                                 => 'm4a',
        'application/vnd.mpegurl'                                                   => 'm4u',
        'audio/midi'                                                                => 'mid',
        'application/vnd.mif'                                                       => 'mif',
        'video/quicktime'                                                           => 'mov',
        'video/x-sgi-movie'                                                         => 'movie',
        'audio/mpeg'                                                                => 'mp3',
        'audio/mpg'                                                                 => 'mp3',
        'audio/mpeg3'                                                               => 'mp3',
        'audio/mp3'                                                                 => 'mp3',
        'video/mp4'                                                                 => 'mp4',
        'video/mpeg'                                                                => 'mpeg',
        'application/oda'                                                           => 'oda',
        'audio/ogg'                                                                 => 'ogg',
        'video/ogg'                                                                 => 'ogg',
        'application/ogg'                                                           => 'ogg',
        'font/otf'                                                                  => 'otf',
        'application/x-pkcs10'                                                      => 'p10',
        'application/pkcs10'                                                        => 'p10',
        'application/x-pkcs12'                                                      => 'p12',
        'application/x-pkcs7-signature'                                             => 'p7a',
        'application/pkcs7-mime'                                                    => 'p7c',
        'application/x-pkcs7-mime'                                                  => 'p7c',
        'application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp'                                           => 'p7r',
        'application/pkcs7-signature'                                               => 'p7s',
        'application/pdf'                                                           => 'pdf',
        'application/octet-stream'                                                  => 'pdf',
        'application/x-x509-user-cert'                                              => 'pem',
        'application/x-pem-file'                                                    => 'pem',
        'application/pgp'                                                           => 'pgp',
        'application/x-httpd-php'                                                   => 'php',
        'application/php'                                                           => 'php',
        'application/x-php'                                                         => 'php',
        'text/php'                                                                  => 'php',
        'text/x-php'                                                                => 'php',
        'application/x-httpd-php-source'                                            => 'php',
        'image/png'                                                                 => 'png',
        'image/x-png'                                                               => 'png',
        'application/powerpoint'                                                    => 'ppt',
        'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint'                                             => 'ppt',
        'application/vnd.ms-office'                                                 => 'ppt',
        'application/msword'                                                        => 'doc',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation' => 'pptx',
        'application/x-photoshop'                                                   => 'psd',
        'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop'                                                 => 'psd',
        'audio/x-realaudio'                                                         => 'ra',
        'audio/x-pn-realaudio'                                                      => 'ram',
        'application/x-rar'                                                         => 'rar',
        'application/rar'                                                           => 'rar',
        'application/x-rar-compressed'                                              => 'rar',
        'audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin'                                               => 'rpm',
        'application/x-pkcs7'                                                       => 'rsa',
        'text/rtf'                                                                  => 'rtf',
        'text/richtext'                                                             => 'rtx',
        'video/vnd.rn-realvideo'                                                    => 'rv',
        'application/x-stuffit'                                                     => 'sit',
        'application/smil'                                                          => 'smil',
        'text/srt'                                                                  => 'srt',
        'image/svg+xml'                                                             => 'svg',
        'application/x-shockwave-flash'                                             => 'swf',
        'application/x-tar'                                                         => 'tar',
        'application/x-gzip-compressed'                                             => 'tgz',
        'image/tiff'                                                                => 'tiff',
        'font/ttf'                                                                  => 'ttf',
        'text/plain'                                                                => 'txt',
        'text/x-vcard'                                                              => 'vcf',
        'application/videolan'                                                      => 'vlc',
        'text/vtt'                                                                  => 'vtt',
        'audio/x-wav'                                                               => 'wav',
        'audio/wave'                                                                => 'wav',
        'audio/wav'                                                                 => 'wav',
        'application/wbxml'                                                         => 'wbxml',
        'video/webm'                                                                => 'webm',
        'image/webp'                                                                => 'webp',
        'audio/x-ms-wma'                                                            => 'wma',
        'application/wmlc'                                                          => 'wmlc',
        'video/x-ms-wmv'                                                            => 'wmv',
        'video/x-ms-asf'                                                            => 'wmv',
        'font/woff'                                                                 => 'woff',
        'font/woff2'                                                                => 'woff2',
        'application/xhtml+xml'                                                     => 'xhtml',
        'application/excel'                                                         => 'xl',
        'application/msexcel'                                                       => 'xls',
        'application/x-msexcel'                                                     => 'xls',
        'application/x-ms-excel'                                                    => 'xls',
        'application/x-excel'                                                       => 'xls',
        'application/x-dos_ms_excel'                                                => 'xls',
        'application/xls'                                                           => 'xls',
        'application/x-xls'                                                         => 'xls',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'         => 'xlsx',
        'application/vnd.ms-excel'                                                  => 'xlsx',
        'application/xml'                                                           => 'xml',
        'text/xml'                                                                  => 'xml',
        'text/xsl'                                                                  => 'xsl',
        'application/xspf+xml'                                                      => 'xspf',
        'application/x-compress'                                                    => 'z',
        'application/x-zip'                                                         => 'zip',
        'application/zip'                                                           => 'zip',
        'application/x-zip-compressed'                                              => 'zip',
        'application/s-compressed'                                                  => 'zip',
        'multipart/x-zip'                                                           => 'zip',
        'text/x-scriptzsh'                                                          => 'zsh',
    ];

    return isset($mimeMap[$mimeType]) ? $mimeMap[$mimeType] : false;
}
```